# Help to understand the proof of partial derivatives of homogeneous functions

Tags: proof-writing, partial-derivative

I found [this](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorial/HOM.HTM) short proof that says the partial derivaties of homogenous functions of degree $k$ is homogeneous of degree $k-1$. Here is the proof in its entirety:

[image]

I am lost at the very first step of the proof which says to differentiate with respect to $x_i$ both sides of the equation:

$f(tx_1,tx_2,\dots,tx_n)=t^kf(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$

Based on my understanding of partial derivates, if I were to differentiate the left hand side, I will get this:

$tf'_i(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$

Which is not the same as what the proof says it should be.

Please advise.

Comment: Why would you lose the $t$s on the left?

Comment: Because I thought the partial derivative of the left hand side is equal to $tf'_i(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. Since the partial derivative of $f(x,y)=x+y$ with respect to $x$ is 1 and the partial derivate of $f(tx,ty)=tx+ty$ is $t*f_x(x,y)=t*1$.

Comment: Ah. Take a homogeneous function of higher degree, say $f(x,y) = x\cdot y$, where the partial derivatives are not constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer Noted. Thank you and lesson learned.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck on this question too. This proof seems to imply that $f_i$  evaluated at $x = tx$ equals $f_i(tx)$ (the i-th derivative of the function $f(tx)$, or $f_{tx_i}(tx)$ for better notation, but this isn't always the case.

Comment: @Rainroad did you solve this? it's bugging me also!

Comment: @CormJack: I'm looking back at this and I'm not sure what I was confused about back then haha. Can you explain the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hey @Rainroad thanks for replying. The notation for the chain rule I was finding confusing, but I worked through it and it did make total sense in the end. The trick for me was just writing $f(sx_1...., sx_n)$ as $f(g_1(x)....,g_n(x))$ where $g(x) = sx$. Thanks for checking in, hope your maths and life are well haha!

Comment: I think @Rainroad, setting $(g(x) = tx$ is essentially what you commented, as then you get the partial of $f$ with respect to $g$ multipled by the partial of $g$ with respect to $s$ which is where we get our extra $s$ from, while keeping the $sx$ in $f$. I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure, do each step carefully. Write 
$$ \phi_t(x)=(tx_1\ldots tx_n).$$
Therefore you are trying to compute 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( f\circ \phi_t\right)(x_1\ldots x_n).$$
Now use the chain rule.

Comment: $f'_i(tx_1,tx_2,\dots,tx_n) = f'_i(\phi_t).\phi_t(x1,x2,\dots,x_n) = f'_i(tx_1,tx_2,\dots,t_xn)$

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that $f_i$  evaluated at $=$ equals $_()$ (the i-th derivative of the function $()$, or $_{_}()$ for better notation? But we know this isn't always the case, right?

Comment: @Rainroad: this is just a choice of notation. This one I wrote years ago is a kind of fool-proof method, devised precisely to avoid the misunderstanding you point out.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: Sorry, I still don't quite understand. Let's ignore your answer for the moment and go back to the original proof. The lhs should be $tf_{tx_i}(tx_1, tx_2,...tx_n)$ (t times the i-th derivative of the function $f(tx)$ or $df(tx)/d(tx))$, while the RHS should be $t^k f_{x_i}(x_1, x_2,...)$ ($t^k$ times the i-th derivative of f(x) or $df(x)/dx_i$). Did I do my chain rule right?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it ([from here](http://econ.ucsb.edu/%7Etedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/ChuckWilsonhomogeneousfunctions.pdf)):

> **Theorem 2:** If $f : R^n_{++} \to R$ is continuously differentiable and homogeneous of degree $\alpha$, then each partial derivative $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $\alpha − 1$.
>
> **Proof.** For fixed $x ∈ R^n_{++}$ and $\lambda > 0$, define each $g_i, h_i : (−x_i,\infty) \to R$ by $g_i(t) = f(\lambda (x + e_it))$ and $h_i(t) = \lambda^{\alpha}f(x + e_it)$ Then the homogeneity of f implies
> $$g_i(t) = f(\lambda (x + te_i)) = \lambda^\alpha f(x + te_i) = h_i(t)$$
> and therefore
> $$g'_i(t) = h'_i(t)\quad \mbox{for all}\quad t \in (−x_i,\infty)$$
> But
> $$g'_i(0) = D f (\lambda x) \cdot \lambda e_i = \lambda f_i(\lambda x)$$
> $$h'_i(0) = \lambda^\alpha Df(x) \cdot e_i = \lambda^\alpha f_i(x)$$
> So
> $$f_i (\lambda x) = \lambda^{\alpha−1}f_i(x).$$
> $\blacksquare$

And to answer your question directly i expand the formula you have doubts in:
$$t\frac{\delta f(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)}{\delta (tx_i)} = t^k \frac{\delta f(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\delta x_i}$$

Comment: This proof makes more sense to me but I still struggle to understand the original proof. Could you help answer my question? The original proof seems to imply that $f_i$ evaluated at $=$ equals $_()$ (the i-th derivative of the function $()$, or $_{_}()$ for better notation, but this isn't always the case.